# No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found

Tags: makefile, cmake, windows-10, zlib, cmake-gui

I get this error for Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and CMake 3.7.1 On Windows 10 Home Edition 64 bit.

Instruction is:

```
Use CMake to build zlib <PFD_DIR>/renderdoc/renderdoc/3rdparty/zlib
```

And I did this (not sure if that's the correct way to do it or what should I have selected for bin dir):
[image]

```
 No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
```

This is how the renderdoc directory structure shows:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had `Visual Studio 15 2017` selected in configure. Cleared the cache and selected `Visual Studio 14 2015 win64` in configure and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks.